# Discord.js Automatically determine command they are trying to use?

Tags: node.js, server, raspberry-pi3, discord.js

Is it possible to make something that will turn an attempted command into the real command?

Ex: I type "pign" instead of "ping", is it possible for it to determine that it is the "Ping" command?

Comment: Maybe you want to add some aliases

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The simplest way is to add aliases is to add fall through on a switch/case.  However the official [Discord guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/dynamic-commands.html#how-it-works) has a rather comprehensive write-up on creating a much more advanced command processor by creating your commands as modules.  This won't fix all possible human errors though, you still have to predict what will be typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is a "Did You Mean?" feature, which would handle simple typos and aliases in strings. There are many libraries that can help with various levels of complexity and features ranging from simple arrays of aliases up to bayesian matching, but here's one that seems to do a decent basic job: https://www.npmjs.com/package/didyoumean